# Trying to get property of non-object in json from API

Tags: laravel, api, controller, laravel-blade

I'm using the Discord API to get the members on a Discord guild to display 10 randoms users and display it in the view with blade using the `foreach` method.

I'm getting the JSON from the API, getting the members array of it and sclicing it to return only 10 members to send it from the controller to the view.

The problem is that, when I want to parse it and use an element of the array (`avatar_url`), it's not working and I'm getting this error message: `Trying to get property 'avatar_url' of non-object`

Here is my controller

```
class IndexController extends Controller {

    ...

    /**
     * Function to get 10 random players on fivem
     * @return array
     */
    private function getServerPlayers() {
        $request = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/683766194884575355/widget.json');
        $decoded = json_decode($request, true)['members'];

        return array_slice($decoded, 0, 10);
    }

    /**
     * Return index view
     * @return Factory|View
     */
    public function index() {

        return view('index')->with('players', $this->getServerPlayers())->with('clients', $this->getServerClients())->with('members', $this->getDiscordMembers());
    }
}
```

Here is my view

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-all-bets" role="tabpanel"
                            aria-labelledby="pills-all-bets-tab">
                            <div class="responsive-table">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="col">Nom du joueur</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Statut</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach($players as $player)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><img src="{{ $player->avatar_url }}">{{ $player->username }}</td>
                                            <td>En ligne</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I think that the problem is kind of dumb but I'm blocked on it, I need some help !

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `avatar_url` like this:

```
<td><img src="{{ $player['avatar_url'] }}">{{ $player['username'] }}</td>
```

because what you pass to view is an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `json_decode` returns an array and not an object.

You can pass the arguments to the view using:

```
        return view('index',[
            'players' => $this->getServerPlayers(),
            'clients' => $this->getServerClients(),
            'members' => $this->getDiscordMembers(),
        ]);
```

And then display them in the view using:

```
<img src="{{ $player['avatar_url'] }}">{{ $player['username'] }}
```